# Add link to autocompletion's documentation

Tags: monaco-editor

Is there a way of having a clickable link on [autocompletion's documentation](https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/api/interfaces/monaco.languages.completionitem.html#documentation)? I tried adding raw HTML and it's being escaped for security reasons (and that's a good thing).

Cheers!

[image: Autocompletion's documentation escapes HTML]

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it's possible: the doc states that [completionitem.documentation](https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/api/interfaces/monaco.languages.completionitem.html#documentation) can either be a string, or a [`IMarkdownString`](https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/api/interfaces/monaco.imarkdownstring.html).

So to add a link, just use the markdown syntax instead of pure HTML. For example:

```js
monaco.languages.registerCompletionItemProvider('json', {
    provideCompletionItems: function(model, position) {
        return [{
            label: '"nullif(expression)"',
            kind: monaco.languages.CompletionItemKind.Function,
            documentation: { 
                value: "The NULLIF function... [see Google](https://www.google.com)" 
            },
            insertText: '"nullif(expression)"'
        }];
    }
});
```